# How to make Tabbed Pane Visible

Tags: java, swing, awt

Warning: very ignorant beginner at hand!

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

import java.awt.event.*;

public class TabbedGUI extends JFrame  {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public TabbedGUI() { 

        JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
        JTabbedPane tab;
        tab= new JTabbedPane();
        TopPanel tp;
        tp=new TopPanel();
        Dimension d = new Dimension(800,600);
        tp.setPreferredSize(d);

        tp.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(800,600);
        setBackground(Color.PINK);

        //MiddlePanel 
        MiddlePanel mp;
        mp=new MiddlePanel();

        this.add (mp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        mp.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(800,600);

        //BottomPanel
        BottomPanel bp;
        bp=new BottomPanel();
        this.add (bp, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        bp.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(800,600);

        tab.add(tp);
        tab.add(bp);
        tab.add(mp);
        this.add(tab);

        p1.add(tp, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        p1.add(bp, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        p1.add(mp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        tab.setPreferredSize(d);

        tab.setVisible(true);
        this.setVisible(true);

        TopPanelC tp1;
        tp1=new TopPanelC();

        BottomPanelC bp1;
        bp1=new BottomPanelC();

        MiddlePanelC mp1;
        mp1=new MiddlePanelC();

        JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
        JTabbedPane tab1;
        tab1= new JTabbedPane();
        tab1.add(tp1);
        tab1.add(bp1);
        tab1.add(mp1);
        this.add(tab1);

        this.setVisible(true);

        p2.add(tp1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        p2.add(bp1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        p2.add(mp1, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        tab1.setPreferredSize(d);
        tab1.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
            new TabbedGUI();
    }
}
```

Create a new GUI called “TabbedGUI.java”.  Add a TabbedPane to the JFrame.  The TabbedPane should have 2 tabs.  The First Tab should be the same as #1 above, a form for Student data.  The Second Tab should look very similar, but would be used to display and change Course Data.  A Course should have 4 textFields, “Course ID”, “Course Name”, “Description” and “Credit Hours”.

Comment: Start by not extending everything from `JFrame`.  Use `JPanel` as base component and when you're ready and these to an instance of `JFrame`

Comment: *"How do you add the 2 frames"* You can't a frame can't be added to anything

Comment: So the 2 frames(Course and Student I spent so much time on are now Panels?)

Comment: If that's what you need, yes

Comment: Well I need them to turn into Panels for the frame to switch between each one

Comment: You will need to convert them some kind of component if you want to add them to anything, yes

Comment: I don't get it you obviously do, I don't

Comment: `StudentGUI` can't extend from `JFrame` if you want to add it to some other container (like the `JTabbedPane` or `JFrame`), it must extend from from viable `Component` class, like `JPanel`

Comment: Alright so I edited it, it is now a Jpanel but now I have 28 errors.

Comment: 1) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow. 2) A single blank line of white space in source code is *always* enough.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant. 3) *"WARNING: VERY IGNORANT BEGINNER AT HAND!"* Stop **SHOUTING** at us!

Comment: I'm sorry, I forget that it is considered 'Shouting' on the web. It was just a warning because some people get really frustrated with me, So i had to warn, if you don't like dumb questions don't bother answering because I know nothing of programming..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JFrame` (or any other window based container) can not be added to anything else, you need to change you UI so that the components extend from something like `JPanel`

Don't ever extend directly from top level containers where possible (applets are a different beast).  Instead, build you UI's around a simple container like `JPanel`.  This allows you to decide how and when to use the components, without been locked into a single top level container, as you are now.

The overall process is simple.  `JTabbedPane` is a container, you add other components onto it.  You then add that to an instance of `JFrame` (or what ever container you want to use), for example...

Take a look at [How to Use Tabbed Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html) for  more details

[image][image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TabbedExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TabbedExample();
    }

    public TabbedExample() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
                tabbedPane.add("Student", new StudentGUI());
                tabbedPane.add("Courses", new CourseGUI());

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(tabbedPane);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class StudentGUI extends JPanel {

        public StudentGUI() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            JPanel top = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            top.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
            top.add(new JLabel("Top"));

            JPanel middle = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            middle.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            middle.add(new JLabel("Middle"));

            JPanel bottom = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            bottom.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
            bottom.add(new JLabel("Bottom"));

            add(top, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            add(middle);
            add(bottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        }

    }

    public class CourseGUI extends JPanel {

        public CourseGUI() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            JPanel top = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            top.setBackground(Color.RED);
            top.add(new JLabel("Top"));

            JPanel middle = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            middle.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
            middle.add(new JLabel("Middle"));

            JPanel bottom = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            bottom.setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
            bottom.add(new JLabel("Bottom"));

            add(top, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            add(middle);
            add(bottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Examples like this help me so much you just don't know